# How to print longitude and latitude aes data in regular order

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
# Europe & Oceania city

EUOc1870 <- EUOc_city %>%
  group_by(City) %>% filter(year==1870) %>%
  mutate(avg1870 = mean(AverageTemperature)) %>% na.omit()


EUOc2012 <- EUOc_city %>%
  group_by(City) %>% filter(year==2012) %>%
  mutate(avg2012 = mean(AverageTemperature)) %>% na.omit()

EUOcC <- EUOc_city %>%
  group_by(City) %>% summarise(avg = mean(AverageTemperature),lon=unique(Longitude),lat=unique(Latitude)) %>%
  mutate(avg_diff = unique(EUOc2012$avg2012)-unique(EUOc1870$avg1870))

EUOcC

EUOcC %>% ggplot() + aes(lon,lat,color = as.factor(City),size = as.factor(ordered(avg_diff))) + geom_point() +
  labs(x="Longitude",y="Latitude", color="City", size="avg_diff",
       title = "AverageTemperature difference between 1870 and 2012:\nEU&Oc Cities") +
  guides(color = guide_legend(ncol = 2)) + guides(size = guide_legend(ncol = 2)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5 ))
```

This is part of my code and when I run it, it shows coordinates strangely. Like 110W shows first than 40w. It seems like program recognize alphabet as number. I want make graph by ggplot to show longitude and latitude in order to map shows. What should I do?

Comment: You will need to reformat your data so that Latitude is a numeric vector - ie 40W needs to become -40

Comment: You could do something like this to convert `EUOcC$Longitude <- as.numeric(gsub('\\D', '', EUOcC$Longitude))`